# How can I add lowess fit line and linear fit line to scatterplot matrix?

Tags: sas, scatter-plot, loess

I wrote the following command in SAS to draw scatterplot matrix. How can I add Loess and linear fit line to the plot?

```
PROC SGSCATTER DATA=HW3;
    TITLE "Scatter Plot Matrix";
    MATRIX Assets Invest Income Delinq CMembers Branches
        / 
        DIAGONAL=(HISTOGRAM KERNEL NORMAL)
        START=TOPLEFT
        ELLIPSE=(ALPHA=0.05 TYPE=PREDICTED)
        NOLEGEND;
RUN;
```

Comment: Since the `matrix` statement doesn't support options for adding loess and regression lines (at least as of v9.4), my guess is that the only way you'll be able to do this is to code the matrix yourself using `layout lattice` in `proc template` with individual plotting statements for each cell...